# Best way in storing data from input types

Tags: php, html, variables, storing-data

I'm creating a simple database for resume' of employees and I only know the basic storing of data from input types to PHP variables.

here.

```
$surnamex = $_POST["surname"];
$firstnamex = $_POST["firstname"];
$middlenamex = $_POST["middlename"];
```

But I saw other forms of storing data like

```
$logo_type = stripslashes( $_POST['type_logo'] );
```

are there any other form of storing data from input types to PHP variable?
If yes what is the best way of storing data to PHP variables?

Comment: best way of storing data? ..... use database?

Comment: Google `PHP Data Sanitization`. That is what that code is doing

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting misleaded

```
$logo_type = stripslashes( $_POST['type_logo'] );
```

the above statement is just removing backslashes if any present in the post variable and then storing it in $logo_type variable.

You can read more stripslashes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Answer (score -1):

It totally depends on what the data is, and what you're expecting to do with it.

For example, if you're planning to put it into a database, you'd need to do something to prevent **SQL injection** attacks. Traditionally that would be this:

```
$variable = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['variable']);
```

But there are better ways to handle data for databases now, like [MySQLi's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

PHP has [a wide range of string manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) that can help to strip unwanted elements from data input (or add wanted elements), but which one(s) to use depends on your use case.

Comment: This function name is wrong. It is `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Not awake yet today. In all fairness if it makes it harder for someone to use deprecated libraries there's probably a silver lining.